# How nginx webserver is configured in open edx Cypress

Tags: django, openedx

I went through the etc/nginx/sites-available/default file but didn't find the configuration setup. In many Documentations explained about application but not how the webserver is configured.

https://openedx.atlassian.net/wiki/display/OpenOPS/Open+edX+Operations+Home

http://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Edx Customized the web server setup within the project folder of openedx ie. After installation of full stack instance. The directory structure as Follows: `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` have link to another directory as follows: `/edx/app/nginx/site-available/` have the lms, cms, xqueue etc.